# How to delete an extra app on my iPhone 5s and return to just the icon on my screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a 5s iPhone & decided to add an extra weather app to the already supplied Weather Channel app. I didn't like the new app and deleted it.

I still have the grey box surrounding the Weather App (that holds multiple apps in a category). How do I get rid of the grey box and leave just the partly sunny icon/app?

(I have the same problem with Photos, i.e., a grey box surrounding it, both necessitating a double click to access them. )

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if I'm talking about the right box, but try pulling that Weather app outside that folder to make the grey box empty. The grey box should delete itself automatically. Then place your weather app wherever you need to.